# Truncating Subscribed Observable

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have an observable with a subscriber that that updates the ui.

```
someObservable.forEach(function(item) {
    updateUI(item);
});
```

My issue is that after some specific user actions I want to ignore
N items from this stream, and handle it slightly
differently (instead of the default handler).

Say the user does an action which I know will produce four items
in the observable, so I want to postpone updating until the
last of these items has arrived.

I was looking into merging this stream with a "control" stream,
and use groupJoin or something to truncate it, but as far as I
can see this will only work with a time window, and not a count
of items, or even a specific order.

Comment: Can you provide an example stream of events here to illustrate what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I'd have a variable `customActivity` somewhere and write the forEach's action roughly like this (my JavaScript knowledge is limited):

```
customActivity = function(item) { 
    received++;
    handle(item); 
    if (received == 4) {
        customActivity = null;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

someObservable.forEach(function(item) {
    if (customActivity == null || customActivity(item)) {
        updateUI(item);
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, exactly. That's a solution. Thank you! I was thinking as I'm a little new to RxJS that there was a certain idiom for dealing with issues like this, but I can handle it like this too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `take` operator to handle only first N values and `skip` to N of them.

```
someObservable
    .take(4)
    .forEach(function(item) {
        updateUI(item);
    });

someObservable
    .skip(4)
    .forEach(function(item) {
        // ... some code
    });
```

> Say the user does an action which I know will produce four items in the observable, so I want to postpone updating until the last of these items has arrived.

In this case `bufferWithCount` can do the job.

```
 someObservable
    .bufferWithCount(4)
    .forEach(function(items) {
        // will be called for batch of every 4 items
    });
```